# string-trim and cl-ppcre cannot trim #\Newline

Tags: string, common-lisp, newline

I use Clozure CL 1.11 on a raspberry pi (machine-type armv61, debian jessie) to run an oracle query via ojdbc7.jar:

```
(defun query (statement)
  (let ((options   ; compiled java filename is Query.class 
        (list "-cp" "/java-files-dir/ojdbc7.jar:/java-files-dir/" "Query" statement))))))
    (with-output-to-string
        (stream)
      (ccl:run-program "java" options :output stream))))
```

The result looks like:

```
"DAVY 
JONES 

"
```

When I coerce the resulting string into a list, I see that the columns are separated by `#\`  and `#\Newline`, whereas the end of the string contains one `#\`  and two `#\Newline` chars:

```
(#\D #\A #\V #\Y #\  #\Newline #\J #\O #\N #\E #\S #\  #\Newline #\Newline)
```

I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2640875/664404) and [CLHS](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_stg_tr.htm) thoroughly, but still cannot understand why `string-trim` cannot trim anything with `#\newline`, `#\linefeed` or `#\return`, and

<del>(cl-ppcre:regex-replace "#\Newline" (query "...statement...") "")</del>
(cl-ppcre:regex-replace #\Newline (query "...statement...") "")

**also doesn't work**, whereas

```
(cl-ppcre:split #\Newline (query "...statement..."))
```

successfully splits columns into a list like `("DAVY " "JONES ")`.

## EDIT

I noticed that the strikethroughed code above with `"#\Newline"` apparently caused a confusion that I may have called string-trim with "#\Newline", but this was a typo.

Both calling `(cl-ppcre:regex-replace` #\newline `...)` and `(string-trim '(#\Newline) ...)` cannot get rid of #\newlines.
Actually I can handle my job by calling `(cl-ppcre:split #\Newline`, which I may even prefer in some circumstances.

However, I want to understand why calling string-trim with `'(#\Newline)` trims the #\Newlines at the end of the string, but cannot trim #\Newlines between the words.

Comment: Which call of `string-trim` does not work for you? For instance, in CCL on a Mac, `(string-trim '(#\Space #\Newline) string)` works correctly.

Comment: @Renzo I already tried a more extensive list. Didn't mention it to not clutter the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> (cl-ppcre:regex-replace "#\Newline" (query "...statement...") "")
> ```

The problem here is that you can't use the character syntax like `#\Newline` inside a string. It will be simply read as a string of 8 characters.

As Renzo mentioned in the comments, you can give `STRING-TRIM` the characters to trim as a list instead of a string.

```
(string-trim '(#\space #\newline) "DAVY 
JONES 

")
;=> "DAVY 
;   JONES"
```

You can also just write the newline in the string, although that will look pretty ugly (you could also use [CL-INTERPOL](http://weitz.de/cl-interpol/)):

```
(string-trim " 
" "DAVY 
JONES 

")
;=> "DAVY 
;   JONES"
```

In regular expressions, you should use `\n` for newlines.

```
(cl-ppcre:regex-replace-all "(\\n|\\s*$)" "DAVY 
JONES 

" "")
;=> "DAVY JONES"
```

That uses `(\n|\s*$)` to replace all newlines, as well as all whitespace before the end of input.

Comment: Please see my edit, the call to cl-ppcre:regex-replace with "#\Newline" was a typo. I want to understand why calling `string-trim` with `'(#\Newline)` can trim the `#\Newline`s at the end of the string, but cannot trim `#\Newline`s between the words.

Comment: @barerd `STRING-TRIM` only trims from the beginning and end. The first sentence in the hyperspec description for it: "string-trim returns a substring of string, with all characters in character-bag stripped off the beginning and end.". You should just use `(remove #\newline string)` if you want to remove all newlines everywhere.

Comment: Well, apparently, I did not read the CLHS that thoroughly. My apologies.